# I want to show the background process of progressdialog when retriving data from listview in Android

Tags: android

I want to retrieve data from database. So i decided to use `ProgressDialog`.

I want to allow the user to see how many records to be added to the list view in background
.
please help me,

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: display your code. You can use the asynctask for that.

Comment: Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: final ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                "", "Please wait....");
        myProgressDialog
                .setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {


                    }
                });
myProgressDialog.dismiss();
}}.start();

Comment: this is code but i want to display than this record are added and other are left in background in listview

Comment: restate please.  All thats clear from your question is that you are retrieving some data in the background.  And you are showing a progress dialog.  Thats not enough to answer the question.

Comment: What do you want to display exactly and where do you want to display it?

Comment: i want some code that display in background to user knew that this data should be get other are left from database

Comment: Do you want this displayed in the progress dialog?

Comment: So something saying 100 records retrieved and 900 remaining?

Comment: i have listview when retriving data from database i wnt that user knew that this files should get others are left from the database

Comment: Is that what you want to say? and should it go into progress dialog?

Comment: In any event thats up to you, but where do you want to display it? in the progress dialog?

Comment: Yes it goes to in Progressdialog

Comment: Your question is unclear.  1) What should the dialog show? Where do you want to display this information?

Comment: 2) what is your question about this? What is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: Ok. So you are wondering how to update the message of the progress dialog as the fetches are being retrieved? Correct? with the amount retrieved and amount remaining?

Comment: progressdialog dismiss than and than user see the data.I want to show that progressbar continue than user can see the data and in background listview is get

Comment: I still don't get it.  Please completely rewrite your question. Use different words etc so we know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Use AsyncTask like below to show ProgressDialog

```
    private class FetchRSSFeeds extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);

    /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */
    /** application context. */

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try {

            /**
             * Fetch the data
             */
            Utilities.arrayRSS = objRSSFeed.FetchRSSFeeds(Constants.Feed_URL);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", "error", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

          // Setting data to list adaptar
          setListData();
          txtTitle.setText(Utilities.RSSTitle);
    }
}
```